# How to minimize load time for Swift page with lots of images?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an app that contains a total of about 65 MB of data, mostly in the form of images that are stored as instances of a class. Right now the app runs great, except for one thing: it takes about 10 seconds to load the ViewController that contains all that information. This happens the first time the page loads after the app is opened or is brought to the foreground.

Here's what the code looks like (except there are many, many instances of the AnatomyView class):

```
class SectionViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
class AnatomyView {
        var viewName: String = ""
        var normalImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Logo.jpg")!
        var markedImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Logo.jpg")!
        var steps: [UIImage] = []
        var attribution: String = ""
        init(viewName: String, normalImage: UIImage, markedImage: UIImage, steps: [UIImage], attribution: String){
            self.viewName = viewName
            self.normalImage = normalImage
            self.markedImage = markedImage
            self.steps = steps
            self.attribution = attribution
        }
    }

 let lateralYShoulder = AnatomyView(
        viewName: "Lateral Y",
        normalImage: UIImage(named: "Lateral Y Normal Unmarked.jpg")!,
        markedImage: UIImage(named: "Lateral Y Normal Marked.jpg")!,
        steps: [UIImage(named: "Lateral Y Step 1.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "Lateral Y Step 2.jpg")!],
        attribution: "Case courtesy of Mr Andrew Murphy\nRadiopaedia.org, rID: 48080"
    )
```

What are some strategies to decrease loading time? Is there a way to store the data somewhere else, then import only what's needed? Having such a long loading time makes the app totally unusable.

Edit: Here's how the image displays in the app. There are at most 8-10 images in the scrollview at a time, arranged side-to-side.
[image]

Comment: try to load data in dispatch queue.

Comment: You should avoid assigning default values that don't make any sense. Why bother putting `""` and `[]`? All of these are (correctly) initialized in the initializer. There's no point to give non-sensical default values, only to immediately replace them with the parameters of the initializer

Comment: @HiteshAgarwal: Could you give me some more information on the dispatch queue? I'm pretty new to Swift and programming in general.

Comment: @Alexander: Good to know-- for some reason I thought I need to have a default value there.

Comment: @Nate No, you don't *need* it, and in many you cases you *shouldn't* have it. Don't impose default values where they don't make sense. E.g. a view named `""`, doesn't make sense

Comment: Can you please attach a screenshot or a mockup of how your UI is displaying the images.

Comment: Find a tutorial of how to asynchronously download and cache images in Swift, there are many.

Comment: @iabuseservers: All the images are part of the app as supporting files, since the app will often be used in places without good internet access. Is is possible to use the queue to access the images that are already stored in the app instead?

Comment: What is the file size of these images?

Comment: @iabuseservers They range from about 80-350 KB

Comment: There are a number of possible fixes here, one of which may simply be to reconsider your UI without being completely married to one particular UX. But `80-350KB` is not a large image file by any stretch except when you bunch a lot of them together. Converting your scroll view into a table view (since they are the same thing) to take advantage of lazy loading may be the silver bullet. Or getting all of those images down to `<50KB` and pushing to a new view controller that displays them in full-res may be more desirable if you must display them all together at once.

Comment: I would suggest converting your scroll view into a table view (and remember, `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` so the scroll view's delegate, if you're using one, plugs right in to the table view's delegate).

Comment: I ended up coming up with a solution where only the initial images to be shown were loaded in viewDidLoad, and the rest were loaded in the dispatch queue. Finally back to quick load times! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the info as is shown, if you are using a UIScrollView to show all the info the loading time is big, but if you divide the info in a way of grid with UIColllectionView or UITableView the content loads as the user scroll, and the time drops down a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to have a look at CATiledLayer and the following Apple example:

From the description:

"PhotoScroller" demonstrates the use of embedded UIScrollViews and CATiledLayer to create a rich user experience for displaying and paginating photos that can be individually panned and zoomed. CATiledLayer is used to increase the performance of paging, panning, and zooming with high-resolution images or large sets of photos.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html